# How to merge a sponsored stellar account with '0' XLM balance

Tags: merge, account, stellar

I create a sponsored account with '0' XLM balance. To remove it using the sponsoring account, I use the **accountMerge** operation, but the subsequent **endSponsoringFutureReserves** operation fails to access the merged account - preventing the whole transaction from running. If I create a sponsored account with '0.0002' XLM balance, I can merge it when it is the transaction's source. Can the merging be done by the sponsoring account instead? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regular (non-sponsored) transaction with the `account_merge` operation and then wrap that transaction in a [`FeeBumpTransaction`](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/fee-bumps) paid by any (e.g. the sponsoring) account.